# Does Free Software Foundation's guidance about SaaS disallow usage of password vaults?

Tags: security

Password vaults, which utilize public and (likely passwordized) private keys to host and protect *principally-non-human-memorized-passwords*, are a kind of [SaaS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service) that remotely  stores and supplies password data to a user over a network. They have become quite common in the last five years; I even had a case when two information security "experts" (the best word I can use two describe them in that context) were surprised to know that I don't use a password vault.

I know that Richard Stallman (who is the founder of the FSF) is totally against SaaS, so I ask:
Does the Free Software Foundation's definition of "Free Software" disallow the use of password vaults (which are always SaaS)?

Comment: My problem of the question that it looks like a cloudy statement. Please cite some reference or so. Where did FSF/Stallman said some like this?

Comment: There are open source password vaults which you can run on your own computer, or on a network computer that you control. So it's not true that they are automatically "SaaS."

Comment: I think I've clarified the question so that previous criticisms no longer apply, so I've correspondingly cleaned up the comments. If anyone has further issues (or thinks that previous issues remain unresolved), please do continue to voice those in new comments as needed.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: under the FSF's definitions, I'd say the remote storage of encrypted passwords is too simple and too secured of an operation to count as problematic SaaS. However, modern password managers may do much more than this core functionality, which could run contrary to the FSF's recommendations.

Full analysis:

[The FSF regards SaaS as an issue](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy//po/who-does-that-server-really-serve.ko-en.html) that is distinct from proprietary software:

> SaaS and proprietary software lead to similar harmful results, but the causal mechanisms are different. With proprietary software, the cause is that you have and use a copy which is difficult or illegal to change. With SaaS, the cause is that you use a copy you don't have. [...]

> Many free software supporters assume that the problem of SaaS will be solved by developing free software for servers. [...] But if the programs on the server are free, that doesn't protect you as the server's user from the effects of SaaS. They give freedom to the operator, but not to you.

The FSF's issues might be restated as

1. With SaaS, you give away your data to an external operator, and
2. You cannot modify a SaaS offering, even if the source code is free (instead, you must modify the free code and make your *own* service), so your computing done on someone else's service is done in a way that you cannot control.

However, the FSF makes it clear that not all network services are objectionable SaaS:

> Does avoiding SaaS mean you refuse to use any network servers run by anyone other than you? Not at all. Most servers do not raise this issue, because the job you do with them isn't your own computing except in a trivial sense.

> The original purpose of web servers wasn't to do computing for you, it was to publish information for you to access. Even today this is what most web sites do, and it doesn't pose the SaaS problem, because accessing someone's published information isn't a matter of doing your own computing. Neither is publishing your own materials via a blog site or a microblogging service such as Twitter or identi.ca. The same goes for communication not meant to be private, such as chat groups.

So, could the remote components of a password vault be said to be "doing your computing for you" in any substantial way? It seems like a password vault service has two parts:

1. A client to generate, encrypt, decrypt, and output your passwords
2. A service to store and serve encrypted passwords to the client

Functionality #1 has no network component, so we can be sure it is not problematic SaaS. #2 handles an extremely simply use case that neatly matches the FSF's acceptable use of a network service "publish[ing] information for you to access".

Functionality #2 needs only to store encrypted blobs of data. It is possible for a service to do this without giving away your sensitive data (since it is encrypted before submission) and without preforming any other computation beyond storing and re-serving that encrypted data upon request. In fact, these requirements are so easy to satisfy, they can be abstracted onto any arbitrary storage provider: one practical example is KeePass, a FOSS password manager, which supports a number of external services (Dropbox, OneDrive, as well as arbitrary network locations via FTP and SSH) to store and serve your encrypted passwords.

All of this means that remote storage and retrieval *can* be done in line with the FSF's recommendations: there does exist (both in theory and in actual fact) a password manager with remote storage that the FSF would find unobjectionable. However, it is also completely possible for a particular software/service to supply vault functionality in a way that does not conform to the FSF's recommendations. In particular:

- Any storage model that does not let the user enforce privacy of their passwords with cryptographic certainty is worthless from a privacy perspective. If the service remotely holds or generates either cryptographic keys or unencrypted passwords, then there can be no guarantee that the service respects the privacy of your passwords.
- A storage model that doesn't let you retain your passwords locally puts you at risk of the service failing to give you your own passwords one day (e.g., either because they went bankrupt or you didn't renew your subscription).

Comment: Where do you draw the line between "problematic SaaS" and "unobjectionable SaaS"? When it becomes "not too simple and secure"?

Comment: @oleosecuritet Looking at the linked article, the FSF doesn't supply a bright-line test (and I'd guess they view it as a spectrum of "more problematic" to "less problematic"), but it makes clear the two points I identify in my answer. Security of the service (namely, pre-submission encryption) eliminates the first problem of sharing private data, while the simplicity of the service trivializes the second problem (the service is doing a bare minimum of computing on your behalf).

Answer (score 2):

With great respect to apsillers' analysis, and with complete submission to the observation that "*if you want to know what Stallman thinks on a particular point, you need to ask him*", I'm not quite so sure that "*the act of using a service to store encrypted passwords is one that the FSF finds unobjectionable*".  Quoting from the same essay that my colleague quotes, I note the view that "*SaaS does not require covert code to obtain the user's data. Instead, users must send their data to the server in order to use it. This has the same effect as spyware: the server operator gets the data. He gets it with no special effort, by the nature of SaaS*".

I couldn't have more clearly summarised what I think is the major problem with online password stores: that you send them your secrets, and they promise to look after them.  When cleaved, this problem falls into two issues: firstly, that the service has access to your secrets, and secondly, that if the service goes away (business fails, servers go down, etc.) you don't have access to your secrets.  In my analysis of these issues from a free-software standpoint, I should clarify the alternative: a personal GPG keypair, used to encrypt a file of stored passwords (which is stored on as many of your computers as seems prudent) and used to decrypt same when access to one is required.  I'm a consultant sysadmin, so I have a *lot* of secrets to look after, and that's what I do.

The first of the two issues seems unsurmountably problematic.  No doubt all those secrets are strongly encrypted at-rest by the SaaS provider, but *who has that encryption password*?  If they do, they have access to your secrets.  If only you do, then you've simply swapped the problem of storing one password securely with the problem of storing another, and worse, you have no control over the strength of the algorithm chosen for this, nor over how long the key is, nor how securely it's generated.

The second issue seems similarly problematic: if you want to survive the loss of the online password manager service, you have to have kept a secure-but-accessible copy of all your passwords somewhere else, and then you're left with a *more* complex setup than the free alternative.

As the FSF writes in that essay on how to avoid the SaaS trap: "*For the simple case, where you are doing your own computing on data in your own hands, the solution is simple: use your own copy of a free software application.*"  I can't think of a more clear example of *doing your own computing on data in your own hands* than storage of your important secrets.  Until someone can take Dr. Stallman's mind on the question, I am *far* from convinced that the FSF would be happy with online password storage.

Comment: I do agree if you give a service your private key or unencrypted passwords (or let them generate them for you remotely), then you're certainly running afoul of either or both of the SaaS problems in my analysis. I excluded them from my analysis because I find them to be unthinkably bad practice from a security perspective, but perhaps there are more things in heaven and earth than are dreamt of in my threat model. I think I've made the mistake of limiting my answer's scope to vaults based on the GPG-based approach you've identified as acceptable.

Comment: If the SaaS is simply acting as *internet-connected storage for yet another copy of this file which I securely encrypted*, then I'd agree that's unlikely to fall foul of the FSF on SaaS.  Most SaaS password managers, in my experience, want to be a *great deal* more than that.

Comment: Upon reflection,  I think I was seeking to answer the question, "Does there exist any possible password vault implementation that does not run afoul of the FSF's SaaS concerns?" which seems like a clear "yes, such an implementation can and does exist" whereas your answer considers what problems exist within the typical state of a modern password vault. I'll improve my answer tomorrow to say both "it is possible" as well as "it is often not done, due to feature set X"

Comment: @apsillers I like your answer a lot more now.  Essentially, I think your answer is now a critique of good password managers like KeePass, and mine's a critique of... other... password managers, like LastPass.